# How to ensure the consistency of a multi-threaded simulation in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, random, gsl

I have implemented a certain simulation that is multi-threaded for the sake of runtime. However, this causes an inconsistency between my different runs since I'm using an RNG for my simulations. Even thought the RNG is seeded the same way across the threads, and even though GNU's gsl_rng is supposed to be thread-safe(I think it is) it looks like some form of race condition between the threads leads some to generate numbers before other threads do and as such there are small discrepancies between various runs.
I was thinking that one way to fix this would be to pre-compute a fixed number of random numbers and then assign them manually to the threads. However, there would be a huge overhead to store the random numbers (in the order of millions).
I was wondering if there was any better way to deal with this race condition?

Comment: "Thread-safe" doesn't imply a consistent execution order or result. Are your threads sharing a single RNG? Give them each their own.

Comment: expanding on what @user2357112 said, just store the RNG seed for each thread.

Comment: Give each thread its own RNG?

Comment: I am aware that thread-safe doesn't imply a consistently execution but it's still required for consistency. gsl_rng is thread-safe but the way I am integrating it is what's causing the inconsistency.
I also agree with the above comments: setting up a single RNG for each thread would be better than precomputing. I could seed them with the generated numbers from the parent thread. I didn't think of this initially because my number of threads is not fixed which confused me but shouldn't be a problem for the implementation.
Thanks and sorry for the vague first question on SO.